# Documents is now desktop in This PC drop down in file explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, help-files

I have no idea how I pulled this off but I was trying to follow a tutorial to remove the one drive documents folder and now I just don't have a documents folder in "this pc" in file explorer...

There are now 2 This pc links to my desktop but one of them has the documents icon. Both function as desktop shortcuts.

I have no memory of what tutorial I followed and now I'm forced to go thru `c:\users\` to get to documents.

[Pic of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDrSt.png)

Comment: One potential workaround, at least temporarily, would be to pin C:\Users\[username]\Documents to Quick Access. It wouldn't show up under This PC but functionally it's just as convenient to navigate with.

Comment: Turn on show hidden files and protected files. Then move the desktop.ini files in each folder out of the folder. Do they now show the correct English name of the folder.. Desktop.ini are used to translate the actual folder name which is in English into the language of the user in Explorer and file open save dialogs only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/documents-folder-missing-under-this-pc-windows-10/3ec6337b-8190-41f5-8bec-b948b0fa72e4

Also if needed see : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-re-create-a-missing-my-documents-icon-on-the-desktop-46c95885-5c90-5f41-da84-aad215ba5d17